# Working on F# compiler source code on a Mac

Tags: f#, rider

I would like to open F# compiler solution (FSharp.sln) from https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/ in an IDE on a mac, then make some changes and run the compiler or ideally step through the code.

I tried JetBrains Rider, but it gets stuck soon after opening the solution: "Initial file processing: prim-type-prelude.fs". Code completion is not available.

I also tried opening another solution from https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp, but both Rider and Visual Studio For Mac crash almost immediately.

What's the best way of working on F# compiler source code on a Mac? Is this feasible only on Windows? I'm new to .net and F#.

Edit: I had much better luck with Windows and Visual Studio. Everything worked pretty much out of the box. I was able to run the project, debug selected test and make minor changes with code completion enabled. I might be missing something, but it seems like it's a much smoother experience on Windows than on a Mac.

Comment: The F# compiler is a huge, complex project, so it's entirely possible that your tools are working fine but there's something unique about this project. Since you're new to both .Net and F#, I'd suggest starting with a smaller project to make sure your tools are working. Try cloning https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold, then running its `build.sh` script (which will ask you for things like a project name). Then open *that* in JetBrains Rider / VS for Mac and see if they work. Then make small changes and recompile, to verify that your tools work. Don't tackle a HUGE project just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried it in Rider and VS for Mac, and it worked fine in both. I was able to run Expecto tests, make simple changes and step through the code.  Autocomplete also worked.